# Perl regex extract two consecutive words

Tags: regex, perl, grep, pattern-matching

I am trying to extract strings containing two words separated by one or more whitespace from a list.
Example:

```
@a=("aaa12:.", "lala lulu", "erwer", ",", "lala   loqw  asqwd", "asdas   sadsad", "asasd| asq");
@b=grep {/\w+\s+\w+/} @a;
```

this gives me

```
      'lala lulu',
      'lala   loqw  asqwd',
      'asdas   sadsad'
```

but I don't want to grep the one with three words...

I tried `@b=grep {/^\w\s+\w$/}` but then I don't get any matches. Should be simple, but I just don't get it. Which regex do I need here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\w` only matches one character. You want the following:

```
/^\w+\s+\w+\z/
```

- `^` matches the start of string.
- `\w+` matches one of more "word" characters.
- `\s+` matches one of more whitespace characters.
- `\w+` matches one of more "word" characters.
- `\z` matches the end of the string.

Comment: @user1981275 Please consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow) the answer..

Answer (score 1):

`I tried @b=grep {/^\w\s+\w$/} but then I don't get any matches`

The only reason it doesn't work is because you left off quantifier(s) at
the beginning/end:

```
/^\w\s+\w$/  
    ^    ^
```

where it would work fine if it were `/^\w+\s+\w+$/`

The better way to do it though is add some flexibility with whitespace:  `/^\s*\w+\s+\w+\s*$/`